# Cross-checking the explanation of my answer (linear algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, diagonalization

Please anyone cross-check the explanation of my answer.

> **Question:** Consider the $~5\times 5~$ matrix $A$ such that it's characteristic polynomial is $~(x-2)^3(x+2)^2~$. Now if $A$ is diagonalizable then find the value of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $~A^{-1}=\alpha A+\beta I~.$

**Answer:** Since $A$ satisfies the condition $$~A^{-1}=\alpha A+\beta I\implies \alpha A^2+\beta A-I=0~,$$so the minimal polynomial of the matrix $A$ must be of degree $2$ and is of the above form.

Again it is given that $A$ is diagonalizable and also from the characteristic polynomial it is clear that  it has no zero on the diagonal, so $A^{-1}$ exists.

Now from the characteristic polynomial, possible $2$-degree minimal polynomial is $~(x-2)(x+2)=x^2-4~.$

So Cayley–Hamilton theorem gives, $$~A^2-4I=0\implies A-4A^{-1}=0\implies A^{-1}=\dfrac 14 A~.$$
Hence $~\alpha=\frac 14~$ and $~\beta=0~.$

**Note:** I know one may say there be similar question (not exactly, I think) on here [find $\alpha,\beta$ such that $A^{-1}=\alpha A+\beta I$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3548089/find-alpha-beta-such-that-a-1-alpha-a-beta-i). But here I just want to cross-check my explaination nothnig else.

Comment: Your solution its correct.